# Cook's bark on the sea

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

```
Slightly changed, I am Cook's bark on the sea  
I can, but I am, as targets may be.

Upon the air, I'm part of change,  
though my name, itself, has had a range.

My children, they number quite evenly,  
Except in the times where you may be.

Repeating my start, but once before  
I end with the end of forever.
```

What am I?
Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you:

> Endeavor?

Slightly changed, I am Cook's bark on the sea

> [James Cook's ship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Endeavour) was the *HMS Endeavour*, a.k.a. the HM Bark Endeavour.  (Note that you have to *change* the spelling for this result)

I can, but I am, as targets may be.

> You can *endeavor* to do something.  Likewise, an *endeavor*, itself, is a target, or goal.

Upon the air, I'm part of change,

> [Endeavor Air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endeavor_Air) is a subsidiary of Delta ($\Delta$) Airlines
> <strike>Referencing the Space Shuttle *Endeavour*, the final space shuttle built</strike>  (A reasonable interpretation, but not the intent)

though my name, itself, has had a range.

> Previously called Express Airlines and Pinnacle Airlines.

My children, they number quite evenly,
Except in the times where you may be.

> Endeavor has 8 letters, but in British and older spellings, is spelt 'Endeavour' which has 9.  You have to add a <strike>you</strike>'U' to get that spelling.

Repeating my start, but once before

> The start of Endeavor is 'E'.  It repeats, once.

I end with the end of forever.

> Its end is the letter 'R'

Comment: Take a second look at your thoughts for the second paragraph, but well done, overall.

Comment: Edited.  Does "though my name, itself, has had a range" refer to the word's etymology?

Comment: It doesn't.  It refers to the previous line, with whom it is paired.

Comment: If you'd like, you're close enough for credit.  I can add the missing details, if you wish.

Comment: I hate to bail, but I'm lost on the rest. If I do have the right answer, feel free to elaborate.  Great riddle!

Answer (score 1):

The title refers to

> Captain Cook's seagoing bark, the [HMS Endeavour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Endeavour).

So you might be something like

> [ENFEVER](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/enfever),

since the last line suggests the solution

> ends with the letters "ever".

Your "children" might then be

> individual fevers or sicknesses.

Comment: The other lines?

Comment: @Sid Working on it ... but now that I've seen TBO's answer and KK's comment on it, that could be more likely. I'm kicking myself for finding the right word and then discarding it in favour of a similar one.